# How to remove point from crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I have a number, for example I have 1234.73 when I export report to excel I only get 000001234 and I need to get 000123473   how can I do that

There is my Crystal Report Formula:

```
totext({Myfield},'000000000')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
right('000000000'+replace(totext({Myfield}),'.',''),9)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are never more than 2 decimals you can multiply by 100 inside the Totext like this:

```
totext({Myfield} * 100, '000000000')
```